# Auto layout for a website

Tags: html, css, web, mobile

I'm facing with the following issue: I've just finished the implementation of my website, but something is wrong with the UI layout when I access it using the mobile phone. 
How can the auto layout be done (or be adjusted) if the website will be accessed from a mobile phone ?

```
   <div id="owl-hero" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/venice1.jpg);">
                <div class="caption">
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/venice2.jpg)">
                <div class="caption">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

On the PC it looks like this:
[image]

On the mobile phone, it looks like this (even the menu looks weird):
[image]

Comment: Read about 'responsive design'.

Comment: for this carrousel - the owl css is exactly like it is on the bootstrap page support.

Comment: thanks anyway, the answer bellow is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the code it is a divination...

If you're using `background-image` you can set `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`.

Comment: it makes the image resposive using contain; but it still has some white gap between; thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome, I suggest you become acquainted with mdn docs about background [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background?v=example).